# i got an error when i use Net::SFTP in my perl script (Connection closed by remote host)

Tags: perl, sftp

I got a weird error when i use Net::SFTP to connect to my SFTP server. 
My script get the SFTP connection infomation from oracle, and then use Net::SFTP to connect to a SFTP server.
When I run the `perl` script , it failed with this error:

> Connection closed by remote host. at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/Net/SSH/Perl/AuthMgr.pm

```
# $rSelectInfoRef = (the connection infomation from oracle)
$host = $rSelectInfoRef->[0][2];
$user = $rSelectInfoRef->[0][3];
$password = $rSelectInfoRef->[0][4];

print "[DEBUG] $host|$user|$password|\n";

my $sftp;

eval {
    $sftp = Net::SFTP->new($host, user=>$user, password=>$password);
};
if( $@ ) {
    print "[ERROR] $@";
    exit -1;
}
```

But, When i assign these connect variables directly, the script run successfully. i didn't change the connection infomation. It confused me, the same value but different result .

```
#$host = $rSelectInfoRef->[0][2];
#$user = $rSelectInfoRef->[0][3];
#$password = $rSelectInfoRef->[0][4];

$host = "168.16.5.110";
$user = "test";
$password = "000000";
print "[DEBUG] $host|$user|$password|\n";

my $sftp;

eval {
    $sftp = Net::SFTP->new($host, user=>$user, password=>$password);
};
if( $@ ) {
    print "[ERROR] $@";
    exit -1;
}
```

Comment: You may like to try using [Net::SFTP::Foreign](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign) instead.

Comment: thanks, oh,  you are the writer of the moudle Net::SFTP::Foreign, a few days ago,i still could not figure out the problem, so  i tried Net::SFTP::Foreign, and then my script run successfully .

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is with variables not being evaluated properly. Try this to see if it works:

```
$host = $rSelectInfoRef->[0][2];
my %args = (
    user => $rSelectInfoRef->[0][3],
    password => $rSelectInfoRef->[0][4],
);

my $sftp;

eval {
    $sftp = Net::SFTP->new($host, %args);
};
if( $@ ) {
    print "[ERROR] $@";
    exit -1;
}
```